# How to Build a Counter in an IF statement

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is possible.

I have an IF statement that I am hoping to add a counter to.

Here is my IF statement:

```
        if ($ageOnDec2016->format('%y') > 12)
        {   
            $ageOnDec2016Display = "<span style='background-color: #FFE4E1'>Aged Out</span>";

        } elseif ($ageOnDec2016->format('%y') == 12) 
        {
            $ageOnDec2016Display= "<span style='background-color: #98FB98'>".$ageOnDec2016->format('%y') ."</span>";
        }
        elseif ($ageOnDec2016->format('%y') == 5) 
        {
            $ageOnDec2016Display= "<span style='background-color: #98FB98'>K Start</span>";
        }
        else
        {               
            $ageOnDec2016Display= $ageOnDec2016->format('%y');
        }
```

What I am wanting to do is add a counter in the IF statement.  If I understand counters correctly, I need to initialize the counter outside the IF Statement, as such:

```
     $KStart2016=0;
```

Then, I need to add the counter++ in my if statement.  So, like this:

```
     elseif ($ageOnDec2016->format('%y') == 5) 
        {
            $ageOnDec2016Display= "<span style='background-color: #98FB98'>K Start</span>";
            $KStart2016++;
        }
```

Unfortunately, the code is not picking up the counter.  It only displays the "0" that I have the counter initialized with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you add `$KStart2016++;` inside every IF statements? (including ELSE)

Comment: I did not as I only want to count the number of rows that == 5 to be added to the counter.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: can you put a `die("CHECK");` statement before `$KStart2016++;` to be sure the condition is true at least once?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the condition is true as it is displaying the correct "K Start" echo on output.

Comment: Is this part of a foreach loop? If so you need to initialise the $KStart2016 outside the loop not just outside the if statement, otherwise it may get set to 1 now and then, but then it will be reset to 0 on every new iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why when I delete the initialization of the counter, that it now works.  Wanted to share in case others have this unique problem with counters in an IF statement.

If anyone has any idea on this rationale, please let me know.